# Adding forms to Django Rest Framework ViewSets

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've created some views that subclass directly from `viewsets.ViewSet` rather than from `ModelViewSet`, many (but not all) of which don't have serializers declared on the class explicitly because I don't need them that way.  An example of one such viewset is a "verify email" viewset, that simply takes in a verification code, and then the `.list()` method on the ViewSet looks up the verification code and verifies the user.  No serializer or model necessary, and I use `ViewSet` only so that I can properly register the view in the router.

However, these views are all lacking the form automatically generated at the bottom of the Browseable API pages that the ModelViewSet pages usually have for POST and PUT requests.

What do I need to do or specify to get these forms to appear with my preferred fields for these `ViewSet` subclasses?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have serializer for the viewset.

`BrowsableAPIRenderer` returns in it's `get_context` method:

```
'put_form': self.get_rendered_html_form(data, view, 'PUT', request),
'post_form': self.get_rendered_html_form(data, view, 'POST', request),
```

and `get_rendered_html_form` is looking for serializer defined for view.

it make sense, because you can't process data sent by `POST` or `PUT` without serializer.